# Avoiding duplicate Tabs on tcxPageControl created at Runtime

Tags: delphi, tabs, pagecontrol

I am using `tcxPageControl` and `tcxTabSheet` to create a several `Tabs`. Each `Tab` is created at Runtime, based on a registry from `tbl_Manager`. This `table` keep the name of manager of each employee, and the `Tabs` are the name of manager.

**PROBLEM**

The name of manager is repeated many times, how can I avoid to create `Tabs` with the same name and create only one `Tab`per manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep track of which tabs you've created before, and only create tabs for names you haven't already seen.

If you're selecting the manager names from an SQL query, then use `DISTINCT` so you get a list of unique values.

You could add all the manager names to a `TStringList` with `Sorted = True` and `Duplicates = dupIgnore`. Once you've added all the names, you can read back the contents of the list, and it will be free of duplicates.